# Анимация для кнопки Android.

Tags: java, android

Нужно сделать анимацию,чтобы кнопка улетала вбок, если её потянуть в соответствующую сторону. Можно ли это сделать стандартными средствами или нужна библиотека специальная? Как это сделать?

Comment: Вот готовое решение https://github.com/romannurik/android-swipetodismiss

Comment: библиотеки пишутся людьми и инструментами которые доступны и вам, поэтому "да" - это вполне можно "сделать стандартными средствами". Есть отличный официальный источник для ознакомления со стандартными анимациями от google там 1 в 1 затрагивается ваша тема. Я рекомендую для самообучения: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc_XOgcRukSoKKjewFJZrKV0